# Why is my Treeview object returning one of its item's values without its underscores?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I have a Treeview object `treeview` that inserts data using the following code:

```
treeview.insert(top_name, 'end', branch_name,values=(value_1, value_2), text=branch_name)
```

where `value_1` is a string that holds data that looks like `"1_2_3_4_5"`.

When I run the program `value_1` appears normally in the treeview widget, however when I print the branch's value using the following code:

```
print(treeview.item(branch_name)['values'][0])
```

The output is `12345`

Here is some sample code that demonstrates the issue:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk

root = tk.Tk()
main_frame = tk.Frame()
treeview = tk.ttk.Treeview(main_frame, height = 15, selectmode='extended', columns=('Value 1', 'Value 2'))

treeview.heading('#0', text='Name')
treeview.column('#0', width=500)
treeview.heading('#1', text='Value 1')
treeview.column('#1', width=90)
treeview.heading('#2', text='Value 2')
treeview.column('#2', width=40)

main_frame.pack()
treeview.pack()

treeview.insert('', 'end', "Top", text="Top")
treeview.insert("Top", 'end', "Branch 1", values=("1_2_3_4_5", "val2"), text="Branch 1")
root.update()

print(treeview.item("Branch 1")['values'][0])

root.mainloop()
```

Why is this happening, and how can I retrieve the original value from the treeview object?

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley I have added a code sample that replicates the problem.

Comment: It took me just a few seconds to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51941260/7432) which appears to be a duplicate of your question.

Comment: @BryanOakley hm, I did not find that while researching. Good to know that there is a workaround. Thank you